# getting the excel sheet data in json format with in react js (i tried split() and includes() function )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
[input][1]
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHdgt.png
    output:
    const data = {

[

    "device key":"key1",

    "brandname":"brandname1",

     "version"20,

     contact:[

        {phone:763736762,email:abc@gmaill.com},

        {phone:4536726633,email:def@gmail.com}

     ]
   ],

  [
   "device key":"key2".

   "brandname":"brandname 2",

   "version"90,

     contact:[
       {phone:456445566,email:xyz@gmail.com},

       {phone:456445566,email:xyz@gmail.com},

     ]

   ]

}

code:

  handleFile(file) {
    let json_object ='';
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileName = file.name;   

    const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString;
    reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => {
      const wb = XLSX.read(result, { type: rABS ? "binary" : "array" });


      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 });


      wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {

        var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);

         console.log("length od arr",XL_row_object["length"])
        const jsondata = {
          "list":XL_row_object,
          "filename":fileName,
          "length":XL_row_object["length"]
        }

         json_object = JSON.stringify(jsondata);


      })



          this.props.setTable(data,json_object,);
    };
```

I have excel data like shown in the image. I have to add that data into a 
json format as described  in output.

have to display that information into a table .
(Headers are dynamic)
and have to post the data into backend api call to db.
tried multiple ways
alreday used slice and include functions.

any response is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-excel-renderer.
Simple and exact.

https://medium.com/hashmapinc/render-and-display-excel-sheets-on-webpage-using-react-js-af785a5db6a7